# Python standalone executable

Tags: python, executable

I want to be able to create a Python standalone executable without any dependencies. Basically, an executable that is closed-source so that anyone end-user/client can use my application.
I am aware of the module py2exe; however, it appears that you need some of the .pyc files with it to actually run the .exe file.
I am using Python 2.7.x

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use py2exe. See [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: Alternative you can have a look at PyInstaller: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: not voting to close because Python's pipeline to exe has changed in the last 5-6 years since question mentioned by @zelite

Comment: Using PyInstaller - it looks like you need a 64-bit version of Python (I say that because it is giving me a python27.dll (error code 126) and I was doing some research and that seemed to be the issue) and it does cause dependencies. It creates a dist and build directory. I am asking for a standalone executable.

Comment: Regarding the 64bit. I have no idea. But regarding the standalone exe, there's a command line option to output a single exe: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options search for -F, --onefile

Comment: @zelite That seemed to do the trick. After running pyinstaller yourprogram.py -F 
you can have the .exe file completely dependent from all of the other folders and files that get generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check PyInstaller.  This is an alternative to py2exe

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

> pip install pyinstaller
>
> pyinstaller yourprogram.py